# JQuery UI Accordion Animation

Tags: jquery, height, accordion

I'm trying to use the JQuery UI Accordion to make an accordion that fills the entire window.
Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/NfN94/

The problem is that is you just switch between "Menu 1" and "Menu 2" then "Menu 3" shouldn't move at all. Yet it jumps a bit during the animation, and then pops back into place when the animation is completed.

Does anyone have a fix/work-around for this?

Cheers

Comment: make sure you've eliminated margins on your outer elements, margin-collapse during animation can be hard to catch

Comment: Chrome 17.0.963.79 m
Safari 5.1.4 (753.54.16)

Explorer works (for once).

Comment: Its ok for me in firefox and chrome latest versions